# react-native-sensitive-info gives undefined when trying to get saved data from keychain

Tags: react-native

Thanks for this great library.
    I am using this library in one of my react-native project, but whenever I am trying to get value stored in keychain , is returning undefined in iOS.

```
Here is what is my use case
1-We have an existing "Native iOS App", which is already present in AppStore to download.
2-Now my client is redeveloping the same app in React-Native, and want to provide this new app as an update to existing users.
3-So we are keeping "Bundle ID" of our new (react-native app) same as that of older app (iOS native app), with higher version number ,so that our new will be downloaded as an updated.
4-Let's suppose, an existing user is already logged in the older app, so we want to maintain this logged status , whenever user update app with newer one.
5-In older app (iOS native app), we are saving "Access Token" in keychain, so based on whether "Access Token" is present in keychain, we decide the logged in status of user
6-Now, in newer app (react-native), we have to get that same "Access Token" from keychain, so that we can decide the logged in status of user and can navigate the user to appropriate screen.

I hope that makes sense!

Now when I am using this library, and try to get "Access Token" from keychain, its returning "undefined" in iOS.

Here may be I am doing something wrong, which only you guys can figure out.
This is how I am trying to get saved "Access Token".


    SInfo.getItem("AccessToken", {}).then(value => {
     alert(value);
    console.log("access token is", value); // value1
   });
```

Comment: react-native and react-native-sensitive-info version ?

Comment: Im experiencing same, can someone explain whats happening.  RN--0.54 and SInfo V-- 5.1

Answer (score 1):

I was facing a similar issue and I figured out what is going on, and I'm betting that we're on the same boat.

I'm using `react-native-sensitive-info` in order to store a JWT, not as a simple key like you, but from a reducer (redux) so that the path is `authentication.jwt` and I was expecting to query it as is, but it return `undefined`

After some investigation, I figured out that the `getItem`'s key, refers to the key you give when you configure your store.

For instance, I'm configuring it like so :

```
const persistConfig = {
  key: 'root',
  transforms: [saveJwtOnly],
  whitelist: ['authentication'],
  storage
}
const persistedReducer = persistReducer(persistConfig, rootReducer)
```

Pay attention to the `key: 'root'`. Now, `react-native-sensitive-info` prefix it with `persist:` so that the only available key, in my case, that `getItem` will be able to return is `persist:root`, which returns a JSON of my stored `authentication.jwt` and the `_persist` key from the package.